# Adobe Reader X is displaying incorrect data

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, adobe-reader

Recently in our organization we moved to Adobe Reader X 10.1.2. We have a web application that displays data in pdf format in IE8 on Windows 7 SP1 64-bit PC. We started observing that the same data is being displayed for different items.

It was not the case before. The only workaround we have for now is, logoff the application   and login again to view a different item. This way to view each different item we have to logoff and login ( very tedious ).

Any ideas what causing this behaviour and without attempting any changes in code, what else can be looked at ?

We have verified the logs and traces and found that we are fetching correct data from our DB but it's the display in the pdf that is incorrect.

Let me know if you need any further information.